# MySQL query to get required data from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
RS    Value    Measure    Feature
1     x1       a          5k 
1     x2       b          5k
1     x3       b          10k
1     x4       c          10k
2     y1       a          5k
2     y2       c          5k
2     y3       b          10k
2     y4       d          10k  
.     .        .          .
.     .        .          .
.     .        .          .
```

there are diff. values of RS(like 1,2,3,4,....)

now i want a query(taking only two values of RS, here 1,2) that returns the result as follows:

```
RS    Value    Measure    Feature
1     x1       a          5k
2     y1       a          5k
1     x3       b          10k
2     y3       b          10k
.     .        .          .
.     .        .          .
```

i.e, i want only those rows which have common Measure and Feature.

Comment: try this , SELECT RS ,VALUE ,measure ,feature FROM TABLE WHERE rs IN (1,2) ORDER BY measure LIMIT 4

Comment: it is returning the first 4 rows from set of all the rows whose rs is 1 and 2 ordered by measure.

Comment: then simply leave out the `LIMIT 4`. Its not that hard.

Comment: but even without `LIMIT 4` the query returns the wrong result. I've mentioned what i require in question.

Answer (score 1):

For this you basically need to look at the data twice within the same query and compare the data to itself.  There's many ways of doing it, but the first I could come up with is to just reference the table twice.

Given the table "bar" with this data:

```
mysql> select * from bar;
+------+-------+---------+---------+
| rs   | value | measure | feature |
+------+-------+---------+---------+
|    1 | x1    | a       | 5k      |
|    1 | x2    | b       | 5k      |
|    1 | x3    | b       | 10k     |
|    1 | x4    | c       | 10k     |
|    2 | y1    | a       | 5k      |
|    2 | y2    | c       | 5k      |
|    2 | y3    | b       | 10k     |
|    2 | y4    | d       | 10k     |
+------+-------+---------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

by my interpretation of your requirements (which may be wrong) you want to select all the lines that have at least two entries, where measure and feature match and the "rs" is one of two values.

The query I have come up with is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    bar.rs, bar.value, bar.measure, bar.feature 
FROM 
    bar, bar AS obar 
WHERE 
    ( bar.rs == 1 OR bar.rs == 2 )
  AND
    obar.measure = bar.measure 
  AND
    obar.feature = bar.feature
  AND
    obar.rs != bar.rs 
  ORDER BY
    measure, rs;
```

That is basically saying that you want all the rows from bar where there is a matching entry in obar (which is basically bar by another name), but where the rs column differs.

The result of running the query is:

```
+------+-------+---------+---------+
| rs   | value | measure | feature |
+------+-------+---------+---------+
|    1 | x1    | a       | 5k      |
|    2 | y1    | a       | 5k      |
|    1 | x3    | b       | 10k     |
|    2 | y3    | b       | 10k     |
+------+-------+---------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: well the thing is there are say 200 different `rs` in the table. I want my query to compare any two particular `rs`(that should be input by user, in the example they are 1 and 2) and return the desired result.

Comment: In that case it sounds simpler - `SELECT * FROM bar WHERE rs = 1 OR rs = 2;`

Comment: so what should be the exact query after this addition??

Comment: Well, if all you want is the data for the rows where rs is 1 or rs is 2, then that is the entire query - just that one short `SELECT` line.

Comment: but that will just return all the rows where rs is 1 or 2. i don't need that.the table i put is just an extract from the main table. i want to be able to put any two rs and get the result set containing only those rows which have measure and feature common between those two rs.

Comment: Ok, so a combination of the two selects then?

Comment: yes.. something like that. i want the result of comparison of only two particular `rs`.

Answer (score 1):

You can express this as a `not exists` query:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.measure = t.measure and
                    t2.feature = t.feature and
                    t2.rs <> t.rs
             );
```

Comment: I didn't quite get it. There is only one table.
(I think in your answer t and t2 are two different table?)

Comment: @Elysium . . . `t` and `t2` are aliases for the same table.  You don't give your table a name, so I gave it the awkward but easily typed name of "table".